# How to use loop to to post in successive rows

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

So the excerpt of code that I'll post below has the following goal in mind: Finding all whole number factors of 1000. I have everything else set, except when I hit "run" to have it post each factor (1,2,4,5...) in each respective cell in column A (A2, A3, A4...), it messes something up, posts all of them into A2, and I'm left with only "1" in A2 because that was the most recent thing to be calculated.

Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Problem1Sub()

    Dim MyNumber As Single                              'Declare type of variable for number in question
    MyNumber = 1000                                     'Declare value of variable

    Dim Factor As Integer                               'Declare type of variable for the multiple

    For Factor = 1 To MyNumber                              'Specifies loop for all integers between 1 and MyNumber

        Dim TrueFactor As Single                        'Declare variable that is successful even factor of MyNumber
                                                            'This is a single so when TrueFactor values are pasted, if a decimal results,
                                                            'an error is easily identifiable

        Dim TestFactor As Single                        'TestFactor will be used to identify if Factor will result in a whole number
        Dim RowNumber As Single
        RowNumber = 1
        TestFactor = (MyNumber / Factor)

        If Round(TestFactor, 0) = TestFactor Then       'Checks if TestFactor is a whole number
            TrueFactor = TestFactor
            Worksheets("PastedValues").Activate         'Brings up sheet to paste values on
            Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(RowNumber, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = TrueFactor               'Pastes each TrueFactor value into the next cell in column A
        End If

        RowNumber = RowNumber + 1

    Next Factor

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question - just a comment on your existing code.  Only call Worksheets("PastedValues").Active once, outside of your loop.  Don't bother with Range("A1").Select and the two following lines.  Replace with Cells(RowNumber, 1) = TrueFactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because RowNumber is  defined in the loop so it will always start with the default value.

Edit : 
I improved your code to use a range instead of relying on the Select method :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Problem1Sub()

    Dim MyNumber As Single                              'Declare type of variable for number in question
    MyNumber = 1000                                     'Declare value of variable

    Dim Factor As Integer                               'Declare type of variable for the multiple
    Dim pastecell As Range
    Set pastecell = Worksheets("PastedValues").Range("a1")

    For Factor = 1 To MyNumber                              'Specifies loop for all integers between 1 and MyNumber

        Dim TrueFactor As Single                        'Declare variable that is successful even factor of MyNumber
                                                            'This is a single so when TrueFactor values are pasted, if a decimal results,
                                                            'an error is easily identifiable
        Dim TestFactor As Single                        'TestFactor will be used to identify if Factor will result in a whole number

        TestFactor = (MyNumber / Factor)

        If Round(TestFactor, 0) = TestFactor Then       'Checks if TestFactor is a whole number
            TrueFactor = TestFactor

            pastecell.Value = TrueFactor               'Pastes each TrueFactor value into the next cell in column A
            Set pastecell = pastecell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next Factor

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, my roommate actually just figured that out right before you did! Also thanks for the tip from Silent D and the "tidy up" editing from Clifford!